# Exposing Postman Global variables as Jenkins Choice Parameters

Tags: javascript, postman, newman

I have a postman collection which I have managed to run from Jenkins using Newman.

I have a groovy pipeline in which I install the dependencies included in my package.json (Newman in this case).  From here, I can run a shell script to call the collection:

```
  stage( 'DEV: Install Dependencies' ) {
      sh 'npm install -g newman'
      sh 'npm install'
  }

  stage( 'Running API Tests') {
  sh 'bash ./scripts_uat/create-new-product.sh'
}
```

create-new-product.sh calls the parameterized create-new-product.json which uses a number of global vars held in a file global-vars.json, a snippet of which below:

```
   //create-new-product.json
    .... 
    "body": {
                "mode": "raw",
                "raw": "{\n  \"dept\": \"{{department}}\",\n  \"prodId\": \". 
 {{productId}}\",\n...
```

I am unclear how I can expose the global vars within Jenkins such that they can be passed as Choice Params from within Jenkins.

A snippet of the global-vars.json:

```
{
"_": {
"postman_variable_scope": "globals",
"postman_exported_at": "2020-02-27T14:37:33.884Z",
"postman_exported_using": "Newman/4.5.7"
},
"id": "3147c1d3-e108-4689-ad7b-0cc719647103",
"name": "globals",
"values": [
  {
  "type": "any",
  "value": "8293004039",
  "key": "product_id"
  },// more vars
```

How would I expose {{productID}} such that it can override the value within global-vars.json?

Can anyone give me some pointers? There is probably a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#newman-options

This gives the entire command-line options for Newman

so you can use `--global-var "<global-variable-name>=<global-variable-value>"` to override global variable values.

As we know the precedence of variables is as follows:

(Precedence increase top to button , meaning local> has more precedence than global)

[image]

so passing an environmental variable as : `--env-var "<environment-variable-name>=<environment-variable-value>"`

will also override the value

Comment: thank you, that makes sense

Comment: @Steerpike could you up vote also

Comment: apologies, now done :)