# Passing global variables to Newman (Postman) from Jenkins

Tags: javascript, postman, newman

I have a Postman Collection with Global Variables that I am running via Jenkins (successfully), but I want to expose choices for the variables as Choice Parameters within Jenkins.

I asked an initial question here, as I'm building understanding: 
[Exposing Postman Global variables as Jenkins Choice Parameters](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/44113/exposing-postman-global-variables-as-jenkins-choice-parameters)

...which set my fundamental understanding.

I'm just a little confused as to the format of the variables as passed from Jenkins to Newman CLI.

At present, I call my collection from within a shell script:

```
//paths to global & env vars up here...
run_collection() {
  collection=$1
  newman run ${collection} -e ${PM_ENV_VAR_PATH} --export-globals ${PM_GLOBAL_VAR_PATH} 
  -g ${PM_GLOBAL_VAR_PATH} --global-var "userCode={{userCode}}"

  if [ "$?" == 1 ]; then
    echo "should fail the build"
    exit 1
  fi

sleep 1
}
```

I have a `global-vars.json` in which I've tried to parameterize the userCode as follows:

```
{
  "type": "any",
  "value": "{{userCode}}",
  "key": "userCode"
}
```

Then in Jenkins my Choice Parameter is as follows:

[image]

This fails, probably for obvious reason - the userCode from the dropdown is not being passed.  What is the syntax I need to use in the global-vars.json and passed to the CLI?  When I use a hardcoded value such as:

`--global-var "userCode=8978"`

Then it successfully overrides any hardcoded value on global-vars.json

Comment: which plugin are you using ?

Comment: DId you try $userCode instead of {{userCode}} in your groovy

Comment: @PDHide in Jenkins, I am using Pipeline plugin and calling the script from there - I've added a snippet to the question

Comment: u don't have to parameterise it in global-vars,  and for script try --global-vars=${params.UserCode} or --global-vars=${UserCode} or --global-vars=$UserCode , try any of these works

Comment: Why are you using --export-globals ${PM_GLOBAL_VAR_PATH}, this won't use the global variable but stores the variable to the file specified. You have to use --globals  ${PM_GLOBAL_VAR_PATH} if you want to use the global file

Answer (score 1):

**Created a project**

[image]

**Called below command in windows batch step:**

```
echo %user%
```

**Output**

[image]

So the variable is being stored as environmental variable , hence for shell script you can use

```
echo $UserCode
```

**Your final shell command would be:**

```
//paths to global & env vars up here...
run_collection() {
  collection=$1
  newman run ${collection} -e ${PM_ENV_VAR_PATH} --export-globals ${PM_GLOBAL_VAR_PATH} 
  -g ${PM_GLOBAL_VAR_PATH} --global-var "userCode=${userCode}"

  if [ "$?" == 1 ]; then
    echo "should fail the build"
    exit 1
  fi

sleep 1
}
```

Note: both $variable and ${variable} are same in shell script. ${variable} is used for parameterisation, you can read more at:

https://superuser.com/a/935427

so you can use both ${UserCode} and $UserCode

**Also:**

Why is -`-export-globals ${PM_GLOBAL_VAR_PATH}` used, this won't use the global variable but stores the variable to the file specified. You have to use `--globals ${PM_GLOBAL_VAR_PATH}` if you want to use the global variable file